# I want to place theses objects along this curve without rotating the object along the curve

Tags: curve-modifier

[image]

[image]

As you can see the objects are rotating along the curve, but in the IT scene they are vertical and not rotated. If someone could please help me that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi, there, FPV. I feel you could....  1: Remove the noise from this question. There seems to be an awful lot going on that has nothing to do with your problem? What are 'the' objects? 2: Bear in mind that we are strangers to your project.. What is 'the IT scene'?  At the moment, this post is vulnerable to closure as 'unclear'.  You can edit, to focus it more on what you need to fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way: create a single vertex, give it an *Array* and a *Curve* modifier in order to array it along the curve with a *Constant Offset*:

[image]

Also enable the *Instancing* of the vertex (*Vetices* option):

[image]

Parent the object to the single vertex, it will be duplicated on each vertex:

[image]